# Can I use a subset of the bits of a uint64_t to store a pointer to reliably access locations in an mmaped buffer in an x64 system?

Tags: c++, operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm building a custom dynamic memory allocator that uses a mmaped buffer of size 8<<20 as the heap.

My mmaped buffer:

```
memory_buffer::memory_buffer() {
void* buf = mmap(nullptr,    // maybe set a 40bit addressable addr?
    this->size,              // Buffer should be 8 MiB big
    PROT_WRITE,              // We want to read and write the buffer
    MAP_ANON | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);
                     
assert(buf != MAP_FAILED);
this->buffer = (char*) buf;
}
```

I reserve the first 2048 bytes of the buffer to store freed-allocation metadata, and the remainder is used as allocable heap space. Clearly, I would like to:

1. Keep the metadata struct as small as possible, and
2. Of 64*n bit size (due to alignment considerations).

My planned metadata struct, memcopied into the mmaped buffer:

```
struct freed_allocation{
uint64_t ptr_and_size_and_flag; //bitmasks to access relevant fields. (flag:1bit, size:23bit)
}
```

I would like to store the pointer to a buffer location in the 40 leftover bits. Is there a reliable way to do this?

Comment: Are you writing C or C++?  `memory_buffer::memory_buffer()` looks like C++; it is not valid in C.

Comment: technically c++, my bad.

Comment: Given the size limitations, you could reliably store an offset into the mapped buffer.  You can't reliably store a whole 64-bit pointer in 40 bits.

Comment: I agree. What I'm less sure of is whether I can force mmap to start at some address < 2^40 - 2^23 (to accomodate the buffer). 
From my understanding of virtual memory, the start address of the mmap'd buffer can be restricted this way.

Comment: You might get away with it — you'll have to consult the man page for [`mmap()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) for the systems of interest to you.  You'd probably need to set the first argument to your chosen starting address, and you'd need to steer clear of the program's text segment and data segment.

Comment: In your metadata, don't store pointers - store offsets into the buffer. Then you wouldn't care where the buffer starts. For 8 MiB buffer, offsets would fit into 23 bits.